# Can I use VS Code for two different projects at the same time?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Perhaps this is a really dumb question but I'm trying to use VS Code to write code for two different courses--one focusing largely on Node.js, the other focusing on React running on top of Node.js.

I obviously don't want to mix files and folders for one project with the files and folders of the other project.

Let's assume I open the main folder for the first project and work on the project's files for a bit. If I then open the main folder for the second project and start working on that project's files, will VS Code keep the files and folders of the second project separate from those of the first?

If the answer to my question is yes, does VS Code use separate editors to maintain access to the two separate projects?

Thanks in advance for your responses!

Comment: You can add multiple folders to a workspace.

Comment: Use `File | Add Folder to Workspace`

Answer (score 0):

u can use `.code-workspace` file

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces

> .code-workspace

```
{
  "folders": [
    {
      "name": "nodejs",
      "path": "./nodejs"
    },
    {
      "name": "react",
      "path": "./react"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can surely seperate them: just open each project by "open folder" in VSCode.